# CSS float: left layout moves

Tags: css, layout, html

This is the css file for two division one at left and one at right=>

```
div#id_div_loadwhat {
    float: left;
    width: 74%;
    padding-right: 5px;
}

div#id_div_rightside {
    float: left;    
    width: 25%;
    height: 100%;
    border-left:solid thin #ff9900;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

When there is no text or data in left side division the right side division moves to the left.

But i want to right side division at it's right side position for all time.

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"When there is no text or data in left side division " --> Just don't let the "left side division" empty, just put a `"&nbsp;"` inside it.

---

If you just want to keep the left div "absolutely empty" as it is, just apply css rule "min-height" to it with a small value:

```
div#id_div_loadwhat {
    float: left;
    width: 74%;
    padding-right: 5px;
    min-height:18px;
}
```

Comment: Is there any option to fix the problem editing the css file not putting anything in that division ?

Comment: Yes, you can apply the css "min-height" to the left div.

Answer (score 1):

what you need is to specify the height on the left div.. either with a min-height or height

this will solve your problem..

and one more thing, the padding-right should be 1% not in 5px because it will miss your style when the resolution is small.

Comment: Are you telling to give a height: 100%; for div#id_div_loadwhat {
 ?

Comment: it depends on you.. this will work and min-height will work too.

Answer (score 0):

Give the right side div float:none and see if that works.

Comment: float: none didn't work, it overlaps with the left side div .